# Sign a message digest using DER encoded certificate in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, cryptography

I'm stuck at this API: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/certificateProvider.
Please don't bother to go into the details, its optional.

So I want to sign a message digest using a DER encoded certificate. The issue I'm facing are the steps where we need to get a privateKey handle from the certificate and finally sign the digest message.

By the way if you are going to suggest JSRSASIGN, or forge, please give specific function name in that, because I'm wrapping my head around these libraries for hours without any result.

Comment: Just to make sure: you have seen the "This API works only on Chrome OS" warning and it applies to you?

Comment: DER is a binary encoding. So, I'm wondering how you're representing binary data in JavaScript.

Comment: @ArtjomB. using ArrayBuffers.

Comment: @Xan Yes Sir, Thanks for pointing out, but I am aware of that and all other things have been taken care of (I am working on Chromebook), I am just not sure of those two parts (as mentioned in question).